# Google Map GPolyline - how to toggle visibility on and off

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

guys,.I draw a GPolyline and want it shine every 2 seconds, I wrote below function, I think it should work,but it doesn't,after 2s, it disappear,but after another 2s, it should appear,but it never does. But when I use 2 alert, it will become normal at every pausese. What's wrong ?

```
function DrawRoute()
    {
        var pts = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < GlobalMarkers.length; i++)
        {
            pts[i] = GlobalMarkers[i].getLatLng();
        }
        Route = new GPolyline(pts);

        map.addOverlay(Route);

        if( ShineObject == null)
        {
            ShineObject = setInterval("ShineRoute()",2000);     
        }
    }

    function ShineRoute()
    {                   
        if(Route != null)
        {               
            if( Route.isHidden() )
            {
                Route.show();
                //alert("show");
            }
            if( !Route.isHidden() )
            {
                Route.hide();
                //alert("hide");
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using google maps api v3, the correct option to hide or show a polyline is as below:

```
if(Route.getVisible()){ 
      Route.setVisible(false);
   else{
      Route.setVisible(true);
   }
```

Comment: But now I use v2, why it doesn't work ? Every alert pause I can see it disappear and appear, that's strange.....